# If $(x+1)^2 - 2x>2(x+1) +2$, then $x$ cannot equal which of the following?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

See: [Nova GRE Math Bible. Page-$235$.](https://greworldknowlegde.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/nova-gre-math-bible.pdf)

> Problem #$10$.
>   If $(x+1)^2 - 2x>2(x+1) +2$, then $x$ cannot equal which of the following?
>   (A) $-5$
>   (B) $-3$
>   (C) $0$
>   (D) $3$
>   (E) $5$

$(x+1)^2 - 2x>2(x+1)+2$
$\Rightarrow x^2+2x+1-2x>2x+4$
$\Rightarrow x^2>2x+4-1$
$\Rightarrow x^2>2x+3$
$\Rightarrow x^2-2x-3>0$
$\Rightarrow x^2-3x+x-3>0$
$\Rightarrow x(x-3)+1(x-3)>0$
$\Rightarrow (x+1)(x-3)>0$

So, $x>-1$, and $x>3$.

[image]

Since $-5$ and $-3$ are outside the range of number-line, the answer is:

- (A) and (B).

---

But, the correct answer is, (C), and (D).

---

**What is wrong with my solution?**

Answer (score 3):

$(x+1)(x-3)>0$

There are two possible cases:

Case 1: Both $x+1>0$ and $x-3>0$ are true. This happens if and only if $x>3$.

Case 2: Both $x+1<0$ and $x-3<0$ are true. This happens if and only if $x<-1$.

The answer should be $x<-1$ or $x>3$.

Comment: $x-1>0$? how come?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake

Comment: "Note that both cases are correct (but in each case, both expressions must be correct in order to count), so the answer should be $x<-1$ or $x>3$." ------ couldn't understand. kindly, elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is fine until you conclude from $(x+1)(x−3)>0$ that $x>-1$ and $x>3$.

Rather, if $(x+1)(x-3)>0$, then $x+1$ and $x-3$ are both positive or both negative.

Answer (score 0):

$$(x+1)^2-2x>2(x+1)+2\iff (x+1)^2>4(x+1)\iff \begin{cases}
x+1>4&if\ x>-1\\
x+1<4& if \ x<-1
\end{cases}$$
$$\iff x>3\text{ or }x<-1,$$

Only (C) and (D) are correct.